# Python - Program is not receiving input

Tags: python

A simple addtion program:

```
def addition(a, b):

    print( 'input a')
    a = input()
    print( 'input b')
    b = input() 
    c = a + b
    print (c)
```

Above give me a *EOFError: EOF when reading a line*

I know it's something simple, but I cannot see it.

Comment: Dont you want to give two numbers for `addition` like `addition(5,10)`

Comment: This code will not give any error as you say, did you miss to include anything? and as a tip, this is not how `int` addition works, this is `str` addition

Comment: Just an unrelated note: you can use a string as an argument for the input() method, ie. `input(“input a”)`

Comment: Also, why does you function input `a` and `b` only to reassign them?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?
You may want to write it as: `print(c)`. That is no space in between. 
Secondly, `input()` will give you the input in a string format. Learn how you can convert them into integers and then add the numbers. Like this, you'd be able to concatenate the input values. Ex: '6' and '2' will give you '62' as an output. Thirdly, there is no need to have a and b as function parameters because you are asking the user to input these numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, this is finally how i coded it

`Def Addition(a,b):
       return = a + b
`
thanks for everyone's response.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a complete program, This error usually occur due to a syntax error of parenthesis.
Here you are taking input, you first must convert that input to int, for the addition because input takes input as a string.
And if you are taking a,b as input inside the function what are those (a,b) parameters therefor.
If you want to call the function with parameters, first take the input outside the function and then call the function with those parameters.

Comment: Maybe include some code to make your answer, more effective

Answer (score 0):

EOFError: EOF when reading a line. This error occurs mainly due to syntax errors like completion of paranthesis. Check whether you've indented your contents properly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if in the function you are already feeding a and b, why are you asking for it again. Either feed them, or ask them in the function. I have given the solution and reason for error both.
Try one of these 2 snippets

```
def addition():
  print( 'input a')
  a = input()
  print( 'input b')
  b = input() 
  c = a + b
  print (c)
addition()
```

OR

```
def addition(a,b):

  c = a + b
  print (c)
print( 'input a')
a = input()
print( 'input b')
b = input() 
addition(a,b)
```

***ERROR***
The EOF could be occuring if you did something like this

```
def addition(a,b):
print( 'input a')
a = input()
print( 'input b')
b = input()
```

Here you stared to define a function but did not indent it so Python crashed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you need to choose if you would like use arguments in your function or not. I see that you would like to print input a and b hence you shouldn't add arguments in the function just ask for the input inside the function. Also, you can declare multiple variables in one line as below.

```
def addition():
    a, b = input("Write a and b separated by a comma").split(",")
    print("a: ", a)
    print("b: ", b)
    c = a + b
    print (c)

addition()
```